# How do I uninstall Tor browser from Windows 7?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help

I need to get detailed instructions how to completely remove Tor browser from Windows 7.

Comment: If your running winows 7 you could try a system restore at a point before you had Tor.

Comment: i think so i had some luck in uninstalling it....
download revo uninstaller pro free trial pack from...
http://www.revouninstallerpro.com/
instaLL it and open it to find a window....
On leftmost upper side, click on view->hunter mode....
u will find a pointer on rightmost corner by default in this way....
[![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7GqB8.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7GqB8.jpg) click on that pointer and drag it on the desktop shortcut icon of tor browser follow the next simple process and all the files related to tor browser in your laptop will be deleted.....
A

Answer (score 6):

Delete the folder you unpacked it to, as simple as that.

Or to make sure all traces are gone use something like fileshredder to make sure its fully untraceable (it's used for removing folders and files and overwrites with random data).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is that simple - if you need the space - just delete the folder.

The Tor Browser is self contained. All its disk activity is contained inside its folder.

Your Firefox profile and settings are not affected by the fact that you downloaded or are running the Tor Browser. It doesn't make any changes to your operating system and by default it doesn't store anything about what you did while using it.

When you start the Tor Browser, it is the only program that is routed through the Tor network. You can use it alongside Firefox, the web sites that you visit through Firefox wont be routed through Tor.

If you need to route another program through the Tor network, while using the Tor Browser, you must manually configure it to use the socks proxy running on port 9150 on 127.0.0.1

When in doubt, you can check if you are routed through Tor by visiting https://check.torproject.org/

Be aware, that when you delete files, they leave traces on your disk. That means, that even after you delete the folder, a forensic investigation could find that you at one time had downloaded the Tor Browser, but not how you used it. In contrast, it should find almost everything that you used your standard browser for, even in private mode.

One way to counteract that, is to keep the Tor Browser on an usb drive.

Also, at minimum try using full disk encryption.

A better approach will be to use [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) on that usb drive.

Comment: Pretty useless information considering Im having the same problem and it won't delete. I tried a force remover it won't even show on it, a File Shredder deleted the contents but still can't delete the file or the browser file. files are now empty but still won't delete and I tried delete before, in between and after, no good then I tried using freeraser and it just won't go away. So I tried making it on another file altogether and it won't work at all. Seems these files MUST be gone before I can do anything. It's that simple? Well what the hell do us retarded computer users need to ask for?

Comment: That's probably not the Tor Browser's fault. Something on your computer is accessing data from the folder. You could use a tool like Unlocker, to check which process is accessing the folder and kill it. Alternatively you can mount the Windows hard drive from a live linux and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not useless information just incomplete. Some files are locked because "They are in use by another program" You also need to go to task manager ctrl alt Del keys simultaneously - choose "Start Task Manager" go to "Processes" scroll down to find the "tor.exe" process and "stop the process. You should then be able to delete all the tor files.